# Filter rows based on the total number of years present using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame `df` with these columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df
Cities  Start_date  End_date    data_avail
A       1-03-2000   1-03-2012   12
B       1-12-2002   1-12-2005   3
C       1-04-2000   1-04-2010   10
D       1-04-2009   1-04-2016   7
E       1-04-2003   1-05-2007   5
```

How to know all the cities where at least three years data exits between 2005 to 2010. For example, in the above example only City A, C, and E satisfy the above condition. Hence the expected output is:

```
df
Cities  Start_date  End_date    total_no
A       1-03-2000   1-03-2012   12
C       1-04-2000   1-04-2010   10
E       1-04-2003   1-05-2007   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove possible missing rows by specified columns:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Start_date','End_date'])
```

Idea is create ranges by years, convert to sets for intersection with range `r` with length and then pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
df['End_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date'])

r = set(range(2005, 2011))
func = lambda x: len(set(range(x['Start_date'].year, x['End_date'].year + 1)) & r)
s = df.apply(func, axis=1)

df = df[s.gt(2)]
print (df)
  Cities Start_date   End_date  data_avail
0      A 2000-01-03 2012-01-03          12
2      C 2000-01-04 2010-01-04          10
4      E 2003-01-04 2007-01-05           5
```

Lsit comprehension alternative with output of boolean list passed to `boolean indexing`:

```
df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
df['End_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date'])

r = set(range(2005, 2011))
z = zip(df['Start_date'].dt.year, df['End_date'].dt.year)
L = [len(set(range(s, e + 1)) & r) > 2 for s, e in z]

df = df[L]
print (df)
  Cities Start_date   End_date  data_avail
0      A 2000-01-03 2012-01-03          12
2      C 2000-01-04 2010-01-04          10
4      E 2003-01-04 2007-01-05           5
```

Comment: I am getting this error ````TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer````

Comment: @SaiKiran - It means there are some missing values, how working `s = df.dropna().apply(func, axis=1).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)` ?

Comment: @SaiKiran - Answer was edited. with `df = df.dropna(subset=['Start_date','End_date'])`

Comment: The code is working perfectly. May I know where is the threshold for no.of years in the code? The code looks a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @SaiKiran - It is specified in `range(2005, 2011)`

Comment: I want to know where we should mention the minimum number of years required between 2005 and 2010. In the above example, it is 3

Comment: @SaiKiran - it is `df = df[s.gt(2)]` it means greater like `2`

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

data.csv

```
Cities,Start_date,End_date,data_avail
A,1-03-2000,1-03-2012,12
B,1-12-2002,1-12-2005,3
C,1-04-2000,1-04-2010,10
D,1-04-2009,1-04-2016,7
E,1-04-2003,1-05-2007,5
```

```py
def can_allow(row):
    allowed_years = [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
    start_year = row['Start_date'].year
    end_year = row['End_date'].year
    return len(list(filter(lambda year: start_year <= year <= end_year, allowed_years))) >= 3

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
df['End_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date'])
filtered = df[df.apply(can_allow, axis=1)]
print(filtered)
```

Here's the output:

```
  Cities Start_date   End_date  data_avail
0      A 2000-01-03 2012-01-03          12
2      C 2000-01-04 2010-01-04          10
4      E 2003-01-04 2007-01-05           5
```

Comment: I am getting this error: ````AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'````

Comment: added the content of data.csv. where do you get that error?

Comment: Now it is working after the edit. Thanks for the effort.